# 5 inch TFT LCD for Arduino

Tags: i2c, lcd, shields, tft

I want to use a 5 inch 800x480 TFT display (touch not needed) with an Arduino (mega, uno or due). I'm thinking of buying this display: [link (buydisplay.com)](http://www.buydisplay.com/default/5-tft-lcd-display-module-wvga-800x480-high-resolution-for-mp4-gps). How can I connect this ?

I have also seen some pricier screens with [serial i2c connection.](http://www.buydisplay.com/default/5-inch-tft-lcd-module-800x480-display-controller-i2c-serial-spi), but I don't understand the difference between this and using a shield?

Do anyone have any advice for displays to order and/or shields for Arduino ? Preferably a solution that I can reproduce by my self later for mass-production by doing be own circuit board.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need a driver board to run it. SSD1963 based ones are popular and are often included on the screen, especially the 7" ones on eBay.

Arduinos cannot drive a display directly. Small TFT screens often include the driver chip on them in the form of a Chip On Glass (CoG). That can't be done with the larger screens due to the sheer​ amount of memory needed to store the frame buffer. So an external chip has to be used, or a microcontroller with built in TFT interface.

Note that even with an SSD1963 (or equivalent - see the ones BuyDisplay sell are based on the RA8875) interfacing the Arduino to the TFT screen results will most likely be somewhat disappointing. Especially if you are interfacing using SPI or I2C which will create a bottleneck. Best is to interface with a 16-bit "8080" interface (16 data bits, read, write, chip select, reset and D/C), however that takes a lot of IO pins, and ideally a proper parallel interface to drive it quickly. And you want a lot of RAM for manipulating the data you want to display...

Comment: Ok but I can not use it with the raw display and arduino due?

Comment: No, that does not have a TFT interface in it. Generally you want a SoC, such as is used on the Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone Black, for that kind of thing.

Comment: ok, the problem is that i want to avoid OS based devices and only use micro controllers that i can build by my self with EagleCAD.

Comment: So you will need a display with a driver chip - and that means spending more money.

Comment: and what about this driver? https://www.adafruit.com/product/1590

Comment: okay so basically this kit will work nicely with a Due i guess: http://www.buydisplay.com/default/display-5-inch-tft-arduino-touch-shield-ssd1963-for-mega-due ?

Comment: Ideal, yes. And should be well supported by most graphics libraries too.

Comment: Ok, one last question: Does it matter if I use a Due or Uno/mega with this as the driver has its own chip and RAM memory that run in parallel ? Thanks again

Comment: The Uno will struggle. Also you won't be able to run in 16 bit parallel, only 8 bit parallel, and that will both slow things down and use most of your Uno pins. Better use a Due.